# Using the Iqueryable list result from one query as the parameter for another?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new to query's and cannot find a way to use a query result list as a validator for another query, is this possible?

```
var query = from weather_variables in weather
where weather_variables.area == choice
select weather_variables.wind_speed;
```

This selects a set of monthly wind speeds from a database

```
var power_query = from wind_turbines in power
where wind_turbines.wind_speed = query
select wind_turbines.xxxxxx;
```

Here I want to get the records that match each of the wind speeds in the list, but as its a set and not an individual value, I cannot match the where in this way, is there another way to form this query that would allow me to validate using the querys output?

EDIT: I need an output for each of the values from the list, using contains only gives me values that aren't the same as each other. i.e. 2 months have the same wind speed, only one output from the 2nd query is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query=weather.Where(w=>w.area==choice).Select(w=>w.wind_speed);
var power_query=power.Where(p=>query.Contains(p.wind_speed)).Select(p=>p.xxxxx);
```

Join:

```
var result=weather
  .Where(w=>w.area==choice)
  .Join(power,j1=>j1.wind_speed,j2=>j2.wind_speed,(j1,j2)=>j2.xxxx);
```

Comment: This works, but it cuts out values that are the same, there is 12 wind speeds, one for each month, and i need 12 outputs from the next query, whether they are the same value or not. Thankyou though, ill edit for clarity

Comment: You really should be doing a join then -- updated answer.